# Using the Internet to Meet Collaborators

Tags: research-process, collaboration

Suppose I am a researcher who is interested in finding out what other people might be interested in collaborating on an idea with me. Are there websites or internet communities that function to connect to other people with similar ideas or interests?

I would be interested in answers in any field.

Comment: This seems to be a "shopping" question because you're asking for recommendations. That begin said, check out researchgate.net

Comment: Main problem is trust.  O researchgate, you will get plenty of interests.  However, having never worked with any of these people, how do you know that they won't run off with your ideas?

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus I agree. I would use it as a starting place to find people doing research.